# Textview not getting displayed to rightOf another textView programatically in android

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add textview dynamically to the right of the textView , but textView is not getting displayed.

The statement "**params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1);"** in the below code is creating a problem if i remove that line the textview is getting displayed at random position.

Need to implement this xml dynamically

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/stationnameVal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="KANYAKUMARI (CAPE)"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrivaltimeVal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stationnameVal"
            android:text="SRC"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Code is :

```
    RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(this);
    // first TextView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        TextView stateName = new TextView(DisplayActivity.this);
        stateName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
        stateName.setText("KANYAKUMARI (CAPE)");
        stateName.setId(1);
        stateName.setTextColor(R.color.black);
        stateName.setTextSize(12);
        rel.addView(stateName, params);

    // Adding Second TextView
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

       TextView arr = new TextView(DisplayActivity.this);
       arr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       arr.setText("SRC");
       arr.setTextColor(R.color.white);
       arr.setTextSize(12);
       params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, stateName.getId());
       params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1);
       params2.setMargins(45, 0, 0, 0);
       rel.addView(arr, params2);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the "LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT" to "LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT"?

Regards

Ziteng Chen

Comment: I am actually curious about something. Is it possible to make both TextView's fill the available space using RelativeLayout. Using LinearLayout, `layout_weight would be used. But idk about Relative Layout.

Comment: @Andy you can use Display Metrics to find out the Screen size(width in your case) and set the width of the textView as tv.setWidth(width/2); for both the textViews

Comment: Hmm, that could work. Not a bad idea. Would the same work for 4 or 5 Views correctly? Splitting the space evenly works, but what about odd numbers?

Comment: making params from FILL_PARENT to WRAP_CONTENT solves the issue

Comment: @Andy just divide the width my no.of view you have.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

or this:

```
rel.addView(stateName, params);
```

to

```
rel.addView(stateName);
```

and also change this:

```
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, stateName.getId());
```

to

```
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```

and do the same for param:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```

otherwise remove it, because Kanyakumari and src are not aligned properly.

actually do this to align them:

```
params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, 1);
```

Comment: making params from FILL_PARENT to WRAP_CONTENT solves the issue.